# How to implement next() method

Tags: java

Trying to figure out how to iterate through the `Double` `array` using the `next()` and `hasNext()` method to see if a value exists in the next element.

Comment: Your constructor is wrong `source=a;` only

Comment: It may be helpful if you hold a counter variable, and use that to base `next()` and `hasNext()` off of.

Comment: What is `DataSource`?  (which could/should probably be generic)

Answer (score 1):

You must add a counter that will give your current position. In the hasNext method, you check whether the item is within the range.

```
public class ArraySource {
private Double[] source;
private int position=0;
public ArraySource(Double[] a){

source = a;
}


public Double next(){
    return source[position];

}        

public boolean hasNext(){
    if(position++>=source.length-1){
        position=0;
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double a[]= {2.3,43.4,3.4,4.5,53.0};
    ArraySource as = new ArraySource(a);
    while(as.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(as.next());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The hasNext() method is used to do a boolean check if it is possible to move to the next instance. You are gonna need a cursor(a counter). The next() method is to actually move the cursor and get the next value. I would google how iterator and iterable work for a better understanding.

```
public boolean hasNext(){ if(cursorposition < sizeofstructure){return true;}else{return false;}

public E next(){if(hasNext()){return structure[cursor];}else{throw new Exception();}
```

So the idea of it is to confirm the next position is either true or false, then the next() would actually